# How do I open an existing bada project using badaIDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide, bada

The IDE allows me to create a new project but I cannot find any way to open one of the samples which come along with bada. Using File > Open File... simply opens files in the text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is based on eclipse, Try File => Import => General => Existing projects into workspace